# Выключается бот Aiogram Openai

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-openai

Пару месяцев назад написал бота для перевода текста на китайский язык. Все работало несколько месяцев нормально, но недавно перенес бота на другой сервер и он стал выключаться через какое-то время неактивности. Я так понимаю, что если час его не трогать, он вырубается и при подключении к консоли чистая командная строка без ошибок.

Прошу помочь разобраться.
Сам код бота:

```
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import pprint
import json

file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

openai.api_key = config['openai']
bot = Bot(config['token'])
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "Переведите каждое отдельное сообщение, отправленное пользователем, на китайский язык, не добавляя никаких дополнительных фраз или информации. Не ссылайтесь на предыдущие сообщения и не пытайтесь обобщить предыдущие переводы. Каждое сообщение должно быть переведено только один раз, и последующие сообщения не должны ссылаться на предыдущие переводы. Бот не должен хранить предыдущие переводы и должен переводить каждое сообщение как отдельную единицу. никогда не возвращайтесь к предыдущим переводам, после перевода сообщения забудьте о нем. пользователь может ввести текст на любом языке, вы все равно обязаны перевести его на китайский. Если пользователь прислал вам текст на китайском языке, переведите его на русский."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Translate the text:"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Переведите каждое отдельное сообщение, отправленное пользователем, на китайский язык, не добавляя никаких дополнительных фраз или информации. Не ссылайтесь на предыдущие сообщения и не пытайтесь обобщить предыдущие переводы. Каждое сообщение должно быть переведено только один раз, и последующие сообщения не должны ссылаться на предыдущие переводы. Бот не должен хранить предыдущие переводы и должен переводить каждое сообщение как отдельную единицу. никогда не возвращайтесь к предыдущим переводам, после перевода сообщения забудьте о нем. пользователь может ввести текст на любом языке, вы все равно обязаны перевести его на китайский. Если пользователь прислал вам текст на китайском языке, переведите его на русский."}]


def update(messages, role, content):
    messages = [{"role": role, "content": content}]
    return messages

@dp.message_handler()
async def send(message : types.Message):
    messages = update([], "user", "Переведи следующий текст на китайский язык. Если текст уже на китайском языке, то переведи его на русский язык. Не пиши ничего, кроме переведенной фразы, не пиши изначальное сообщение, пиши только сам перевод без дополнительных слов.:" + message.text)
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages = messages
    )
    
    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Мало информации. Может у вас бот на каком-то бесплатном хостинге, который усыпляет процессы при неактивности.

Comment: Бот на платном хостинге HostVDS, странно что усыпляется именно процесс. Может какую нибудь доп. команду в коде прописать?

Comment: Попробуйте в техподдержку хостинга обратиться.

Comment: С проблемой разобрался самостоятельно. До этого давал команду боту через PuTTY, поэтому он спустя какое то время вырубался. В итоге зашел через сайт-интерфейс в консоль, прописал команду, бот больше не вырубается